# How to make slider discrete?

Tags: dart, flutter, slider

How to make slider discrete look like image above in Flutter?
[slider discrete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2gp6.png)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `divisions` property of the [Slider](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) widget to divide it into equal portions, then you have to put `Text` widgets under them:

```
 Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: 200.0,
  child: Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
   children: <Widget>[

     Slider(min: 0.0, max: 1.0, divisions: 9, value: 0.0, onChanged: null); // you have to provide an `onChanged` function to let slider pointer change place, and to execute other related actions.

     Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

       children: <Widget>[
       Container(
         child: Text('6'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('7'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('8'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('9'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('10'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('11'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('12'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('13'),
       ),
       Container(
         child: Text('14'),
       ),
     ]
   ),
 ]),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying apply code, look good, and number in Container can be apply margin or padding to centered under division node :)

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Flutter, so bear with me, but when going to the docs for Slider [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) they give the example of using integer numbers by setting the label property to

```
    label: _currentSliderValue.round().toString(),
```

This rounds the current slider value to the next integer, which - from what I can tell - makes the values discrete.

I hope this helps.